# Should I build 2 iOS apps with several differences or just combine into one?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm vietnamese. I have an English practice project. I intend to build separately one app for vietnamese and one one for others. Actually they're both a little slightly difference. So, should I combine them into only app. And if I shouldn't then can I have 2 iOS apps with the same name and the same Bundle ID. I've also put ads in my app so will my revenue be affected?

Answer (score 0):

Because they are just slightly different, you should build one app and localize it for English and Vietnamese.

These slight (UI) differences can be made to depend on the current locale.

Bundle IDs are unique in the App Store. App display names are not unique. So it's possible to have two apps with the same display name, but they need to have different bundle IDs.

Even if you'd have larger differences, having two separate apps (i.e. two Xcode projects) is a big step. In case there are a lot of similarities and shared code, one should always first consider having multiple targets (one per app) in the same Xcode project.